# How to retrieve pointer structure in a function

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-tree

I have a struct like this:

```
struct ClientNode
{
string name;
int flightnumber;
int clientno;
ClientNode * right;
ClientNode* left;
};
```

then I have declared a pointer of this struct:

```
ClientNode* root = new ClientNode;
```

in a function I have initialized clientno for root like this:

```
root->clientno = 11;
```

and then I want to send root as an argument to a function:

```
ClientNode newnode;
root = Insert_to_AVL_Tree(&newnode, root);
```

and here is my Insert_to_AVL_Tree:

```
ClientNode* clientclass::Insert_to_AVL_Tree(ClientNode* Node, ClientNode* root)
```

Here is where the error happens, I have initialized root->clientno but it seems that it changes when I pass it to another function thus it can't compare to values in the if, also node->clientno has the correct value that has been read from a file in another part of my code:

```
if (Node->clientno < root->clientno)
root->left = Insert_to_AVL_Tree(Node, root->left);
```

what is the correct way to get the root->clientno value in another function?
[here is the value shown for root->clientno](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2CWk.jpg)

[here is the value for node->cleintno](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzwt5.jpg)

Comment: I have initialized it somewhere else and the value is set correctly. but root->clientno has a value like -88845858

Comment: How do you know root->clientno has changed? Please post a complete code example.

Comment: Why do you need this? Is it an assignment?

Comment: @esmaily I think your first picture shows the value of root (the pointer), not the value of clientno

Comment: @yassin then how can I just access to the exact value of clientno?

Comment: for `node->clientno` it is correct, so do the same for root

Comment: Pleae read [mcve] and try to make a MCVE, getting the balance of "C" and "M" is tricky, but well worth the effort. Very important for allowing useful answers is the "V".

Comment: It seems you are using your debugger incorrectly. The posted code is fine. Do a print of the values and you'll see. `cout << "root->clientno is " << root->clientno << endl;`

Comment: Also the value `cdcdcdcd` in the posted picture seems strange. I can't imagine that it is the pointer value. Seems more like some uninitialized value. Maybe you call the function incorrectly. So show a complete minimal example of the failing code.

Answer (score -2):

For passing Pointer to functions the best way I use is double pointer

```
void clear(int **p)
{
   *p = 0;
}

int main()
{
   int* p;
   clear(&p);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is passing a pointer by simulated reference. To pass a pointer by value  one * is enough. The problem the OP described has nothing to do with that.